# Double URL triggers creates move_uploaded_file() failures

Tags: php, proc-open

This generated severe headaches!

A WordPress post is supposed to process sample data (uploaded as PDF files) and displays the data (after some manipulations and reformatting) on the same post just below.

```
...
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="filepdf" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload data samples (.pdf file)" />
</form>
...
```

That's the PHP code.

```
...
if(isset($_FILES['filepdf'])) {
    $mTime = number_format(microtime(true), 3, '.', '');
    $file_name = $_FILES['filepdf']['name'];
    $file_size = $_FILES['filepdf']['size'];
    $file_tmp = $_FILES['filepdf']['tmp_name'];
    $file_ext = strtolower(end(explode('.', $_FILES['filepdf']['name'])));
...
        $cmd = "./mybinary '$file_name'";
        $outfile = tempnam("/tmp", "cmd");
        $errfile = tempnam("/tmp", "cmd");
        $descriptorspec = array(
            0 => array("pipe", "r"),
            1 => array("file", $outfile, "w"),
            2 => array("file", $errfile, "w")
        );
        move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, '~/' . $file_name);
        $proc = proc_open($cmd, $descriptorspec, $pipes);
...
```

Hours of troubleshooting, but I don't find why this happens ... when I upload a PDF file, the binary `mybinary` in proc_open() fires twice - sometimes (spaced by +/- 200 ms). Let's say 95% of all requests work fine (only one request), but 5% fail due to these double triggers. It seems (?!) that mobile Android devices using Chrome are more affected than other operating systems and/or browsers (not sure at all about that though). This is at least what Apache's access.log suggests. Chrome on my Windows 7 x64 machine doesn't generate these double triggers. The present situation is unacceptable since the binary uses millisecond timecode generated by the PHP code (see above), and this messes up the entire process.

Questions:
1. Is my assumption correct that Android/Chrome sends two requests?
2. If yes, why?
3. Can I avoid that?
4. If yes, how?

I googled about that, and indeed, it seems that `proc_open()` sometimes fires twice, but I didn't find any solution.

The story goes on. If the double trigger occurs, I noticed that the uploaded file is not moved by the `move_uploaded_file()` function. I'm still troubleshooting, but I strongly assume that there is no file to move from `/tmp`. Consequently, I get an error for `proc_open()` since it relies on the uploaded file. I don't see what the browser (Android/Chrome) sends to the server so that no temporary file exists!

Question:
5. Under which circumstances does `move_uploaded_file()` report false?

----- SOLUTION -----

To complete this ... I initially used `PHP code snippets (Insert PHP)` plugin (version 2.0.6 - latest). The php page was in fact only called once, but executed twice. I didn't have any explanation for all this described above (same temp filename, but code called twice, ...).

After I changed the PHP code WordPress integration method into the Shortcode concept, all worked fine (till now). So I believe that this mentioned plugin was the reason for the double triggers?!

And no double clicks - I checked that already right from the beginning. So probably the PHP code itself was not the culprit.

Comment: You should probably check `$_FILES['filepdf']['error']`, it may have more information. Maybe requests are being cancelled without a complete upload. Also, the use of `is_uploaded_file` is probably recommended as well. Maybe someone just double-clicked a submit-button?

Comment: Ok, that's what I did now. I managed to log a few double triggers. `$_FILES['filepdf']['error']` is 0 (false) for both calls. The `$FILES['filepdf']['tmp_name']` is also identical. However `move_uploaded_file()` returns true (1) for the first call and blank (false) for the seconds call. I believe (not sure) that the tmp file for the second file doesn't exist anymore (since moved already by the first call), but why is the code triggered at all at at the first place, and why does `$FILES['filepdf']['tmp_name']` still show the name, and why does `$FILES['filepdf']['error']` report no error?

Comment: It still sounds suspiciously like you're accidentally running the same code twice in a _single_ request, you should make absolutely sure this isn't the case. Although I am not sure how. mod_unique_id from Apache could be a solution, but perhaps loggin request_time_float is sufficient.